# Joining two mongoose collections with many to many relationship

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models which are Product & Category with many to many relationship.

Following are my models

This is the model for Product

```
//Product.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const { ObjectId } = Schema;
const product = {
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: [2, "Too short"],
    maxlength: [32, "Too long"],
    unique: true,
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    index: true,
  },
  category: [
    {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
    },
  ],
  description: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 200,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    maxlength: 32,
  },
  shipping: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["Yes", "No"],
  },
  color: [
    {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Black", "Brown", "Silver", "White", "Blue"],
    },
  ],
  sold: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
  },
  images: [
    {
      public_id: String,
      url: String,
    },
  ],
};
const productSchema = new Schema(product, { timestamps: true });
const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
module.exports = Product;
```

This is the model for Category

```
//Category.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const { ObjectId } = Schema;
const category = {
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    max: 32,
    unique: true,
  },
  subCategories: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
    },
  ],
  parent: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category",
  },
  products: [
    {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "Product",
    },
  ],
  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: "URL can't be empty",
    unique: true,
  },
};
const categorySchema = new Schema(category, { timestamps: true });
//Validate the slug to ensure proper url is given
// categorySchema.path("slug").validate((val) => {
//   urlRegex =
//     /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-/]))?/;
//   return urlRegex.test(val);
// }, "Invalid URL.");
const autoPopulateChildren = function (next) {
  this.populate("subCategories");
  // this.populate("parent");
  next();
};
categorySchema
  .pre("findOne", autoPopulateChildren)
  .pre("findById", autoPopulateChildren)
  .pre("find", autoPopulateChildren);
const Category = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
module.exports = Category;
```

So, product has a foreign keys of category in array of category. Whereas Category has foreign keys of product in array of products. How do you join them ?

I tried this & it doesn't work. It returns empty object

```
router.get("/products", [RequireSignIn], async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const products = await Product.find({}).aggregate({
      $lookup: {
        from: "Category",
        localField: "category",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "ProductCategories",
      },
    });
    return res.status(200).send(products); 

  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(200).send(error);
  }
});
```